# SQL: Outer Join and Count

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have to create a sql statement which shows the sheepname and his/her number of brothers and sister.

This is my sql script:

```
create table breeder (
breederNumber   number(3) primary key,
name            varchar2(20),
residence       varchar2(20),
password        varchar2(20)
);

create table race (
raceCode        varchar2(2) primary key,
raceName        varchar2(20) not null
);

create table sheep (
earTagNumber    number(2) primary key,
father          number(2),
mother          number(2),
raceCode        varchar2(2),
name            varchar2(20),
previousBreeder number(3),
genotype        varchar2(7),
gender          varchar2(1) check (gender = 'M' OR gender = 'F'),

constraint fk_previousBreeder foreign key (previousBreeder) references breeder(breederNummer) on delete cascade,
constraint rk_raceCode foreign key (raceCode) references race(raceCode) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_mother foreign key (mother) references sheep(earTagNumber) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_father foreign key (father) references sheep(earTagNumber) on delete cascade
);
```

[The outcome should look like this](http://snag.gy/XE95c.jpg)

I'm supposed to use an outer join, but I have no idea how the sql statement should look like.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please send sample data? It should be a simple join statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s1.earTagNumber, max(s1.name), count(s2.earTagNumber) 
 from sheep s1
 left join sheep s2 on (s1.father=s2.father) or (s1.mother=s2.mother)
group by s1.earTagNumber
```